# Saving Git changes temporarily

Tags: git

Is `git-stash` what I want to explore? Say I work on my project on my laptop but I need to transfer what I've done so far onto my desktop. Both PCs are sync to a centralized GIT repo. I don't want to commit my changes just yet, I want to pick up where I left off on a different PC.

Comment: Why not just create a temporary branch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git-stash` only saves the changes locally. You can not send that change on a different machine afaik.

What you want is to create a new branch, make the required changes, push it to remote, and pull that branch on the machine where you need it.

Comment: Why use the central repo at all?  Just pull directly to where you want to work

Comment: Because I wouldnt have both PCs at any given time. Laptop goes with me to work, desktop is at home.

Comment: Yes, but the whole point of git (version control) is to keep track of whatever a small change is being made. Since there is a central repo, I see no point in keeping this change private. If it is indeed so private, then why not just send the changed files and why bother with git. I agree though, that pulling directly is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The command `git stash` is for temporarily saving changes *locally* (and reverting to previous state). That doesn't seems to be what you want.

If you have direct access from one computer to the other, you can create another remote that points to the other computer. Then push the changes to that computer, without involving the central repository.