# Is HEAD in git case insensitive on all platforms?

Tags: git

Using msysgit on Windows, I can do this:

```
git checkout head
```

or

```
git checkout HEAD
```

Either works. I don't have a linux environment to test on, but I'm just curious: is `HEAD` case insensitive by design? Is it this way on all platforms?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`HEAD` is case-sensitive on Linux.

For example:

```
$ git checkout head
error: pathspec 'head' did not match any file(s) known to git.
$ git checkout HEAD
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

Git version 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Thanks, plain and simple answer. I do find it unfortunate that msysgit allows bad habits to develop (but maybe there is a good technical reason for the case insensitivity).

Comment: Or (since 1.8.5 IIRC) use `@`.

Answer (score 12):

The case-sensitivity of HEAD is depending on the case-sensitivity of file system of the OS.

When you checkout HEAD, git actually looks for a **file** named "HEAD" under the folder .git. If you type HEAD in small letters, git looks for the file name with small letters. You can see the .git/HEAD file actually contains the hash code of the commit HEAD pointing to.

Because of this, the typical case-sensitivities of HEAD are:

- Case-sensitive on Linux
- Case-insensitive on Windows, MacOS

Comment: Doesn't MacOS use a case-insensitive file system by default?

Comment: Thanks Keith, I do not notice that. @Lorenzo Marcon, are you using case sensitive version of HFS+ in your Mac OS?

Comment: I can repro Lorenzo Marcon's behavior on Mojave with `git --version` returning `git version 2.20.1 (Apple Git-117)`, and my filesystem is case insensitive. For example I can delete file `a` with `rm A`. Also `git push origin HEad` appears to push `HEAD`, and `git symbolic-ref HEad` and `git symbolic-ref HEAD` both return `refs/heads/foo_branch`, and `git branch HEad` and `git checkout HEad` are interesting, and `git branch -d HEad` somewhat surprisingly does the right thing and deletes the `HEad` branch without apparently corrupting my repo.

Answer (score 2):

Answering to cover Mac OSX (Mavericks):

```
$ git checkout HEAD
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

but:

```
$ git checkout head
Note: checking out 'head'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at f44b740... fix if endScreen(s) not present
```

By the way, that hash is the head of the current branch (in my test, the same has contained in `.git/refs/heads/master`)

Interesting behaviour.

(git 1.8.5.2)

Answer (score 1):

HEAD is case sensitive in Linux environment. As far as I know its case insensitive only in mysysgit.

In Linux environment it gives : `error: pathspec 'head' did not match any file(s) known to git.`