# Pushed branch commits not showing on remote origin

Tags: git

1. I cloned the remote repo, `git clone URL` from machine A
2. I created a branch: `git checkout -b my-new-branch`
3. I made several commits to this branch
4. I push to the server, `git push origin my-new-branch`
5. I clone the remote repo from another machine B
6. I `git-fetch`, `git-fetch --all` and several other tricks until my branch shows up.
7. I switch to the branch, `git checkout my-branch`, then `git log`, and none of my commits appear, even though `git branch` shows that I'm on my-new-branch

What's going on? How can I diagnose this issue? Could this be a version mismatch issue?

(I'm on Debian and I have a fairly old version of git: `git version 1.7.10.4`)

Comment: may be when you come to the new branch you should try to do a git pull origin my-new-branch.

Comment: When I do this, it asks me to enter a merge message. But I haven't committed anything new, so I'm confused. What am I merging with what? Only I have been making changes to 'my-new-branch'

Comment: If you have been making change in your new branch after go into it, it will merge the change you did with the file you already commit in your new branch. do a git status to be sure about what files are changed or make a git diff to show the modifications.

Comment: Actually, I haven't made any changes. But just to make sure, I did a `git reset --hard head`, and `git clean -f -d`. After this, git status shows `nothing to commit (working directory clean)`. But I still get a 'merge' prompt when I try pulling

Comment: If you are sure that you are in your new branch then it's not a merge with your master so I have know idear sorry.

Comment: @erjoalgo warning HEAD is [case-sensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25976876/635549).

Comment: Yes, that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In machine B, run `git branch -vv` to make sure the local `my-branch` is tracking the remote `my-new-branch`

If the output show `[origin/master]` for both local branches (`master` and `my-branch`), then `my-branch` is tracking `origin/master` instead of `origin/my-new-branch`

So to fix this you can remove the local `my-branch` by running

```
git branch -D my-branch
```

Then create a new local `my-branch` to track `origin/my-new-branch`

```
git checkout -b my-branch origin/my-new-branch
```

Note: The above command creates the local branch and does check out together.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Although I'm still confused about how that happened.

Comment: On machine B, when you do git fetch and checkout, by default it refers `origin/master` . So while checking out any other remote branch, we have to explicitly mention `origin/<remote-branch name>` after the local branch name you want.